# Cartthob and channel entries. Tag {title}

Tags: channel-entries, cartthrob

EE v2.5.5

On the cart page i need to get image title based on its id.
Instead tag {title} shows the title of cart item.
So high level variable rewrite low level.

```
{exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}<br>
   {title} // shows cart item title, for example "Product 1"

   {exp:channel:entries channel="images" entry_id="{item_options:image_id}" limit="1"}

      {title} //should show image title, for example - "Image 1", but shows "Product 1"
   {/exp:channel:entries}       

{/exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're getting variable collision there. You'll need to embed the inner `channel:entries` tag and pass the `entry_id` to the embed:

```
{embed="_embeds/_cart_item_title" entry_id="{item_options:image_id}"}
```

And then in that template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="images" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" limit="1" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|pagination|categories|custom_fields"}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Tnx, it helped!